# Function to check if custom page is used by page?

Tags: functions, customization, page-template

I have template-clientlist.php now I search on wordpress doc but can find a function on how to check if page used template-clientlist.php

```
template-clientlist.php

<?php
/*
Template Name: Page Of Posts
*/
?>
```

Is there function that exist or custom function to check if page used the custom template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try.

```
$template_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wp_page_template', true );
```

Comment: yeah this one works

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to [is_page_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template)? Comes in handy :)